# PHP: If condition not working inside foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, foreach

I want to show data using a PHP foreach loop that has an If stattement inside. The If statement is accepting some values as TRUE when it should be accepting ALL the values as true.

Printing $phone_array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [phone_number] => (011) 5290-0314
        [type] =>  phone
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [phone_number] => (011) 4711-6948
        [type] =>  phone
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [phone_number] => (011) 4794-9490
        [type] => phone
    )
```

The if statement inside the foreach loop:

```
foreach($phone_array as $value){
    if(isset($value['type']) && $value['type'] == 'phone'){
        echo "Its a phone<br>";
    }
    elseif(isset($value['type']) && $value['type'] == 'mobile'){
        echo "Its a mobile phone<br>";
    }
}
```

This code shows "Its a phone" only once when it should be showing it 3 times.

Comment: Those first two array entries seem to have an extra space between `=>` and `phone`... Can you try `trim($value['type']) == 'phone'`?

Comment: Your foreach loop is working fine. the issue is from the array itself. check to ensure there are no extra spaces

Comment: It is showing "Its a phone" 3 times. See https://3v4l.org/9H4NS

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thank you very much! I haven't noticed. That was the problem.

Comment: As @NiettheDarkAbsol said - that is a typo. You can just modify your code to `&& trim($value['type']) == 'phone'` or fix your data

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is space on your array value, So try to remove white space before compare.

```
foreach($phone_array as $value){
    if(isset($value['type']) && trim($value['type']) == 'phone'){
        echo "Its a phone<br>";
    }
    elseif(isset($value['type']) && trim($value['type']) == 'mobile'){
        echo "Its a mobile phone<br>";
    }
}
```

It might help you.

Comment: Thanks! I used a trim function and a replace function to make sure there's no whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and in my case is working fine, like Festus Yuma posted, it might be your array declaration. I share my code and you will find an extra option condition:

```
$phone_array = array(
    0 => Array(
    'phone_number' => '(011) 5290-0314',
    'type' =>  'phone'
    ),

    1 => Array(
    'phone_number' => '(011) 4711-6948',
    'type' =>  'phone'
    ),

    2 => Array(
    'phone_number' => '(011) 4794-9490',
    'type' => 'phone'
    )
);

foreach($phone_array as $value) {
    # 1 Option

    if($value['type']) {
        if($value['type'] == 'phone') {
            echo "Its a phone<br>";
        } else if($value['type'] == 'mobile') {
            echo "Its a mobile phone<br>";
        }
    } 

    # 2 Option

    if(isset($value['type']) && $value['type'] == 'phone'){
        echo "Its a phone<br>";
    }
    elseif(isset($value['type']) && $value['type'] == 'mobile'){
        echo "Its a mobile phone<br>";
    }
}
```